# mysqldump command returns [ERROR] unknown variable 'local_infile=1'

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I've been trying to create a dump file for local MySQL database since forever but I keep getting the same error.

**The command:** `mysqldump -u user -p sampledb > sampledump.sql`

**The error:** *mysqldump: [ERROR] unknown variable 'local_infile=1'*

I've tried every fix I could find but nothing fixed it:

- checked all `.conf` files for the variable (found none, the files did not even have the variable at all),
- uninstalled and reinstalled MySQL, etc.

I'm able to connect to the db via MySQL Workbench so I've also tried to generate the file via 'Data Export' but even that does not work, it just shows a blank screen.

[image: Workbench error]

I've tried updating the versions but still nothing.

**Are there any other fixes I can try?** I'd really like to be able to migrate the data in the db without having to re-enter them manually

Comment: https://mysql.general.narkive.com/dsnFm4H3/problem-with-mysqldump-and-local-infile

Comment: Try `grep -irn --include=*.cnf local[-_]infile /etc` or `grep -irn --include=*.cnf local[-_]infile /home` to find the offending file.

Comment: `mysqldump --help` tells you which configuration files will be processed.

Comment: @GeorgRichter The error occurs before the help can be output, at least that is the case when checking on Debian.

Comment: I already tried that but there is no file with the variable, which is why I mentioned thst the variable is not in any of my .conf files @user1191247

Comment: @GeorgRichter `mysqldump --help` also returns the same error. In fact, any command I try with `mysqldump` returns the error

Comment: The variable must be coming from somewhere. Try `mysqldump --no-defaults --help | grep -A 1 'Default options'`. If you cannot find the file, you can run `mysqldump --no-defaults` to stop it picking up the invalid variable.

Comment: Have you read Ergest Basha's link yet @Ariah?

Comment: @user1191247 these worked! The first command eventually brought out a .conf file that I wasn't able to find before, and that's where the variable was! I removed it and everything works now, I've been able to create my dump file, thank you very much! 

Thanks everyone, you were all so helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's the resolution that worked for me, special thanks to **@user1191247**:

- **Try `mysqldump --no-defaults --help | grep -A 1 'Default options'`**: this lists out the paths of all `.conf` files in order of priority,
- **Check through each of the files to confirm that they do not contain the culprit variable**: in my case, it was `local_infile=1`. You can check this by running `nano <<the path>>>` or any other editor you use
- **remove the culprit variable**. Done!

> **Another option mentioned was**: run `mysqldump --no-defaults` to stop it
> picking up the invalid variable, but I didn't need to use it.